# 'This email address is already registered' error when updating my account

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, accounts, google

I have already logged into Stack Overflow through my Google account. I am trying to update my account. I am getting this error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account.

Please help.

Comment: Is the error message not clear?

Comment: I have already logged in. Then why is it telling me to login? That too when i am trying to `update` my profile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, this error essentially means you have two profiles out there that both have the same email address set in the profile. You *did* have two accounts "registered" but that was not at any fault of your own. This was completely our doing.

What happened is that we ended up creating a bunch of profiles for old Careers accounts that were never attached to an on-site Stack Overflow profile, so that they could be emailed about the developer story change. Problem: they were bogus accounts that frankly confused us. Since no credential was attached to these accounts (they were literally just a stub with an email attached), our normal tool for finding these accounts wasn't working. The credential-less accounts just didn't show up.

Your account has now been corrected, so you can save your profile with an email again. At some point, all of these extra accounts should end up deleted so it won't affect further users. However, if anyone has a problem with this seemingly random error occurring, feel free to [contact us](/contact) and we'll fix it up for you. If you ever had a Careers account that you never connected back to your network account, chances are you have a blank stub account out there somewhere.

Comment: yeah thanks for fixing the issue. I am able to update my profile with the email field intact.

Comment: @animuson I am facing the same issue. What should I do?

Comment: @animuson same for me as well

Comment: @animuson same here. What should I do ?

Comment: same issue here also, @animuson can you take a look at my account also please?

Comment: @animuson same issue here for my account. What should I do please?  Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the issue on my account as well.