# Email is already registered error on updating profile

Tags: support, bug, profile-page

I was trying to add the GitHub link on my Stack Overflow profile. I entered the link and pressed `Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities`. I am getting the error below.

[image]

Is it a bug? I came across [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336294/this-email-address-is-already-registered-error-when-updating-my-account), but it was not much of a help.

Comment: Have you visited the account recovery link shown?

Comment: @JonClements yes it is showing "Forgot your account's password? Enter your email address and we'll send you a recovery link."

Comment: And did you do so?

Comment: @JonClements Should I do this? I can login and log out without any issues. Why should I reset password now ?

Comment: Looks like you inadvertently (or someone did) created a new account with that email in October. You'll have to use the contact us link at the bottom of the site to confirm you own that email and request the other account be removed. (it has no activity - so if it's yours and you can login to it by requesting a password reset then you can request self-deletion, otherwise as above)