# Unable to change profile details

Tags: bug, profile-page, login, accounts

While updating my profile details I'm getting the following error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: This email address is
>   already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our
>   account recovery page to get access to this account.

Comment: This needs a dev to look into, probably an account merge is stuck: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336294/this-email-address-is-already-registered-error-when-updating-my-account

Comment: but i am having only single account link with my email id

Comment: Maybe there was a temporary glitch as the same issue was reported on MSE y'day: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296912/update-profile-info-does-not-work but that resolved itself. Can you retry to see if you're still facing the same issue?