# Contact support form does not accept valid profile link for merging accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I have the same issue discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336294/this-email-address-is-already-registered-error-when-updating-my-account).

Unfortunately I can not submit the issue using the appropriate contact support form:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Update:

@Cerbrus: I tried to see my logins. Same result as on Stack Exchange:

[image]

Comment: They need to be both for the same site (I think the SO page might even expect them to both for your SO profiles) - you've got one there that's a SE link...

Comment: Ahh... I think I see what's going on here... do you remember creating an SO account about 15 months ago and never using it?

Comment: Yes and I can login with Google and account. The problem is with merging those 2 accounts with same email address.

Comment: My those 2 account are sort of merged because when I login to 1 account, it shows same counter.

Comment: Err no - I think what's happened is you've got login credentials for certain emails, but another account already has the same email as its actual email... The other account is [this one with 1 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6960768/user9376910) - so you'll want to use that in your merge request instead of the stackexchange one... (or if you can - login to that one and request self deletion - it should be immediate) - then you should be able to change the account you're using now details without issues.

Comment: You are confusing the *network account* and a Stack overflow account. *They are already linked*. You can switch between one and the other with links provided on either profile. Merging only applies if you have two seaparate Stack Overflow accounts; both accounts would have a URL starting with `https://stackoverflow.com/users` but with different ids following that prefix. Your network profile has a different ID number but you’ll note that the URL prefix *is different*. Jon found your other account, you need to use the URL for that account.

Comment: I merged your two profiles so you should be all set. Thanks for digging up the other profile, @JonClements.

Answer (score 2):

The "other" profile link is supposed to be a Stack Overflow profile link, because you're trying to link Stack Overflow accounts.

However, that Stack Exchange profile you entered there ***is*** the same profile as your Stack Overflow account. SE / SO account IDs just aren't the same.

You can see it in your [accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/2883481/ali-yousefi-sabzevar?tab=accounts) tab on Stack Exchange. The Stack Overflow link there links you to the account you used to post this question.

Comment: Same result! I updated my answer and took new screenshot from stackoverflow's my login.